# Suggestion regarding Stack Overflow's Close Votes queue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I know you guys discussed  about that topic a lot, but I tried to look in the questions that dicussed that topic if there was a similar suggestion and didn't find (I will delete my question if any), Si I am just wondering if my suggestion would be helpful.

I was thinking that one of the reasons that this queue is too big, would be that it includes many sub categories regarding the reasons behind the flags to close questions: primarly opinion based, unclear, too broad, off-topic (which also include 7 other sub categories!) ...

So, why not just splitting that queue in the same way the flag are splited? Of course, not into ~10 categories as they seam to be which is not really useful as we will end up with a lot of queues, but just into 3 or 4 queues taking in which the number will be a little equal (like 2k in each queue)

Comment: Splitting the queue into flag categories might bias reviewers into trusting the flags more than they should. After all, they're supposed to do an independent review of the question. Plus, what about questions with flags of multiple types?

Comment: Also.... if we're to split the queue in 3-4.... why not give everyone 3-4 times as many close votes? The problem isn't the singular queue but the fact ppl have a limited amount of close votes

Comment: Current queue size is roughly a week's worth of questions - not too bad, considering it includes flags that never age away! Gonna fix that here soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/modernize-the-close-vote-aging-logic

Comment: @Patrice you are right on that, I was just thinking that maybe the number is also scary :) maybe when users see a small number we may get more reviewers

Comment: @Pekka웃 Honestly I didn't thought in all the logic to implement, I think in most cases there is some types that are a bit close, but you are right regarding the ", they're supposed to do an independent review of the question"... Anyway, I understanb that this is not a practical suggestion :) I should auto downvote :p

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't saw that interesting post, BTW Thanks for you and all the other moderators for your efforts